# Como saber se uma div não tem a classe hidden com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mvc

Quero fazer uma negação no if,nesse caso abaixo quero ver a div que NÂO tem a classe hidden.

**Estou tentando dessa forma:**

```
function AddFiltro() {
    if ($("#divcamponiver:not(:hidden)")) {
        alert("CAMPOS DO TIPO DATA");
    }

    if ($("#divcampo:not(:hidden)")) {
        alert("CAMPOS PADRAO");
    }
}
```

Mas os dois `if` estão sendo executados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) para isso:

`if ($("#divcamponiver").hasClass("hidden"))`

`:hidden` isso usado no seletor está buscando a *pseudo-class* hidden e não uma classe chamada hidden. A *pseudo-class* hidden é usada para identificar se um elemento está visível ou não.

Mais detalhes aqui: [Pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Agora se quiser o seletor por essa pseudo-class, deve fazer assim:

`if ($("#divcamponiver").is(":hidden"))`

Aqui um exemplo:

```js
alert("d1 has class= " + $("#d1").hasClass("hidden"))
alert("d1 is:hidden= " + $("#d1").is(":hidden"))


alert("d2 has class= " + $("#d2").hasClass("hidden"))
alert("d2 is:hidden= " + $("#d2").is(":hidden"))
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 2px #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#d1 {
   background-color: yellow;
}

#d2 {
   background-color: cyan;
   display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```